# If $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is Lebesgue measurable and $l \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a line, is $X \cap l$ necessarily measurable in $l$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

[This MSE question asked by Akiva Weinberger](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091006/subset-of-plane-with-measure-1-in-all-lines) (and answer provided by hot_queen) provides a lovely example of a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that, for every line $l \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $X \cap l$ is measurable in $l$, and yet $X$ is not measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$

(To be clear, by "measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$" I mean the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure, whereas by "measurable in $l$" I mean the one-dimensional Lebesgue measure along $l$.)

What about the converse? Is it possible to find a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ that is Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and yet $X \cap l$ is not measurable in $l$ for some line $l \subset \mathbb{R}^2$? (Or can it be proved that all such $X \cap l$ are in fact one-dimensionally measurable?)

Clearly all $X \cap l$ have measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, since all lines have measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and hence all $X \cap l$ are measurable in two dimensions. I am struggling, however, to move from measurability in two dimensions to measurability in one dimension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have provided a counterexample yourself.

If $A$ is any non-measurable subset of $\mathbb R$, then $A\times\{0\}$ is nevertheless Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb R^2$ because it is null. Its intersection with the $x$-axis is $A$ itself, which is not measurable in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ha, excellent, of course! Thank you. Perhaps the condition "$X$ measurable and not null in $\mathbb{R}^2$ would make the problem more interesting.

Comment: @EMalkin: Take $A\times\{0\}\cup [1,2]^2$.

Comment: Lovely, how obvious again. I should have played with it a bit more before leaving the comment.